# Laravel Feature Testing: Factory Records Exist but Test Says Otherwise

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, tdd

I'm having a strange problem with my Laravel feature tests.
I have a `createTeam` method that creates a factory record and persists it in memory-database.

```php
    public function createTeam(): static
    {
        $this->team = Team::factory()->create([
            'name' => $this->user->name . ' Team',
        ]);
        $this->team->assignMember($this->user, TeamRoleTypes::OWNER);

        return $this;
    }
```

Then I go on and try to test an action.

```php
    public function testUserCanDeleteItsOwnTeam()
    {
        $this->createTeam();

        $this
            ->useToken()
            ->deleteJson(route('team.delete', ['team' => $this->team->id]), [
                'name' => 'Second team',
            ])
            ->assertOk();
    }
```

However, the response says `"No query results for model [App\Models\Team] e99a7514-58e2-4d29-91f2-f0c3a034a419"`. When I check the same model for existence in the same test by using something like `Team::find("e99a7514-58e2-4d29-91f2-f0c3a034a419")` and it says it's there!

Does anyone have any idea why such thing happens?

Comment: If the data is in the database and the controller don't see it then maybe is cache problem or you see another (prod database) in your controller than your test (test database) are storing?

Comment: Cache problem can be from redis and different databases from raw queries in you controller. Can you send the code from your controller?

Comment: Hey @KolovosKonstantinos, you can find code snippet links below.
Base Test file: http://pastie.org/p/3Yn450B8FsKLQO6ytwFlSW
Deletion test file: http://pastie.org/p/18zu5ZT4cGnhiLIOKvo75E
Controller file: http://pastie.org/p/7p5VBopSu4d0EkwnG641NO
Routes file: http://pastie.org/p/77ZXJEhB31r9ESBLvQrBgv

If test files and the test API used different databases, why would the same user would be able to authenticate? It only fails with factory generated data. If I generate data through API test call, again it works. Funny.

Comment: You are right for the database is the correct one . Can you assert in your test before the delete route call the auth()->user()->teams() has this specific id so we can exclude the cache also ?

Comment: I remember that was having the same problem because in the invoke method the lazy loading of the $team property are happening through a midleware when you pass a id or an object . I was using the withoutMidleware trait and basically stop this functionality. Take a look at this also is a common mistake

Comment: The ID is there. But it somehow evaporates before calling the API. Here is the weirdness. The factory doesn't reflect between test suite and API yet the actual API call via test suite does. http://pastie.org/p/5grcnKXt1zFRN6hDr0mjPl @KolovosKonstantinos

Comment: So it is in the database but not in the user instance you have in the memory. Definitely then a cache problem as far as I can tell. I thing that your tests misbehave because you keep OLD instances of user . In other words you have different user that you try to test. Assert that and see if helps

Comment: But I'm not checking through the user instance.
1. I create the record using factories INSIDE the test.
2. I call the API to delete the records using the ID I have INSIDE the test.
3. The call returns a 404 model not found error even though it exists in the database
Everything works if I create the records by doing another call instead of using factory method. This is the weirdness :)

Comment: How you update the $this->user->teams when you change it ? You have the correct user ? You assert the $this->user has the correct is as i suggest you?

Comment: @KolovosKonstantinos indeed it is the correct user. The assertion is positive on that part at least...

Comment: @KolovosKonstantinos mate, I found the reason of the failure, you could use the info in the future :) Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the problem lied with the factory and the mystical behavior of Laravel/PHPUnit/Memory DB or whatever...
What happened was caused by the autogenerated factory class trying to fill the timestamp fields manually as can be seen below:

```php
class TeamFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Team::class;

    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => Str::uuid(),
            'name' => $this->faker->name(),
            'deleted_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ];
    }
}
```

The last three definitions were causing the cancer and now everything is working as expected after deletion of these little buggers.